# Access to SAP NPM repository using JFrog fails

Tags: artifactory

We want to integrate/configure the use of SAP's publicly available NPM repository (https://npm.sap.com) in **JFrog (Version: Version Artifactory Professional, 6.12.1 rev 61201900)**. However we encounter the error message "Connection Failed. Error 400: Bad Request" (pls. ref. to attached screenshot).

[screenshot JFrog error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNWmp.png)

We also configured access to other NPM repos (e.g. nexus.scanbot.io, registry.npmjs.org) on the very same host and encountered no such problems at all.

Our JFrog host uses an internet proxy. We tested the connection to the repo using wget successfully:

```
xxx:/export/home/tprepo >wget https://npm.sap.com
--2020-01-09 10:03:33--  https://npm.sap.com/
Resolving [...]... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

We have not found a solution for this problem and are stuck with our problem analysis.
Any ideas?

Thank you and kind regards
Ingo

Answer (score 0):

The https://npm.sap.com doesn't allow the head requests which is causing the npm packages not to be fetched.
Could you try to bypass the head request in the settings of the remote repository pointing to the https://npm.sap.com in the advanced tab of the remote repository. The test connection will again fail with 400, however, you should be able to fetch the SAP packages.